# Point a RigidBody to look in a direction (LookAt)

Tags: math, trigonometry, godot

In Godot I have a `RigidBody` that I would like to turn in 3D space so that it points towards a certain direction. Pretty much a LookAt. I found [this tutorial](https://godot-es-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/physics/rigid_body.html#the-look-at-method), and I've written the below based on it.

Something I find a little confusing is that I'm not sure why it's only worrying about the x axis in the `rotationAngle` - should I be somehow implementing the others too?

```cs
public override void _IntegrateForces(PhysicsDirectBodyState state)
{
    // Push RigidBody in direction that it's facing
    Vector3 forwardForce = GetForwardForce();
    this.ApplyCentralImpulse(forwardForce);

    // Turn RigidBody to point in direction of world origin
    var targetPosition = Vector3.Zero;
    var currentDirection = -this.Transform.basis.z;
    var currentDistanceFromTarget = this.Translation.DistanceSquaredTo(targetPosition);

    GD.Print(currentDistanceFromTarget + " " + currentDirection);

    if(currentDistanceFromTarget > 50)
    {
        var targetDir = (targetPosition - this.Transform.origin).Normalized();

        var rotationAngle = Mathf.Acos(currentDirection.x) - Mathf.Acos(targetDir.x); // Why only x?

        var angularVelocity = Vector3.Up * (rotationAngle / state.GetStep());

        state.SetAngularVelocity(angularVelocity);
    }
}
```

This will work up to a point - if the new `currentDirection` happens to match the positive Z axis, then it just continues in that way.

Comment: Just to be clear. What prevents you from using look_at(Vector3 target, Vector3 up)?

Comment: @RenéKling According to [the docs](https://godot-es-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/physics/rigid_body.html#the-look-at-method) - "using the Spatial node’s look_at() method can’t be used each frame to follow a target"

Comment: @Ian Have you tried the code the docs recommend as an alternative? It is in GDScript, but conversion should be fine